# 漸化式からnumpy配列を生成する

Tags: python, python3, numpy

漸化式となる関数からnumpy配列を高速に生成する方法を探しています。

ある実数値 `a0` と 関数 `f(x)` が定まっているとして、以下のコードをなるたけ実行効率をよくするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

```py
a = a0
L = [a]
for i in range(100):
    a = f(a)
    L += [a]
```

何卒、ご教示ください。

Comment: 参考: [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: 英語版 Stack Overflow での関連質問です：[Is it possible to vectorize recursive calculation of a NumPy array where each element depends on the previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4407984/5989200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どうしても再帰的にしか処理できないのであれば、for ループをどれだけ速く回せるかという話になりそうです。

となると、Numba の JIT コンパイルや Cython のコンパイルを使って高速化するのがひとつの手段です。以下は Cython のコード例です。

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef np.float64_t f(np.float64_t x):
  return 3.5 * x * (1 - x)

cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] generate_by_cython(int n):
  cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] a = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
  a[0] = 0.5
  for i in range(n - 1):
    a[i + 1] = f(a[i])
  return a
```

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。numpyにはそのための関数はないのですね。（コメントにも頂いたとおりvectorizeで出来そうではありますが、これはそのための機能、というわけではなさそう)cython勉強してみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: `f` をイテレータとして定義して `np.fromiter` を使う方法は一応ありますが、そこまで速くないはずです。